# WebClient.UploadValues to WebClient.UploadValuesAsync

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, xamarin, webclient

In my *Xamarin Android* app I have this *WebClient*, which I receive *JSON* from. I want to make it async, but `UploadValuesAsync` is a void method, so I don't know how to receive the *JSON*.
I could also use `HttpClient`, but I don't know how, for the same problem. 
This is the code:

```
using (var webclient = new WebClient())
{
 try
  {
    json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(webclient.UploadValues("http://address", values));
  }
 catch (Exception e)
  {
   string ex = e.ToString();
  }
}
```

Also, how do I detect when operation is done?

Comment: If you're trying to received data from http://address, you probably want to use one of the WebClient.Download* methods instead of Upload*.

Comment: Did you check to see if the documentation for HttpClient had any examples?

Comment: @Frowe the problem is that I also have to upload values

Comment: @Crowcoder did't find anyhing like what I am trying to achieve here

Comment: @Baga  Subscribe the WebClient event [`UploadValuesCompletedEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.uploadfilecompletedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx). When the Upload is completed, `UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs` `e.Result` contains the answer form the server in Byte array.

Comment: @jimi I will try it, thank you, this is to me the more clear answer.

Answer (score 4):

`UploadValuesAsync` is older than the Task class, it is not the method you use with async/await. You want [`UploadValuesTaskAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh472354.aspx) instead and you will be able to await the Task it returns.

Comment: yes sorry I meant it, but it returns a task and I don't know how to get the string from it.

Comment: You just need to await it. Read a intro to async/await tutorial for more info.